# accessing in scope variables inside lambda function or alternative way to achieve the same lisp

Tags: lambda, lisp

I have the following function which does the following job: returns a matrix constraints if a region-map has two nodes as neighbours:

```
(defun map-coloring-constraint (region-map)
  (let* ((node-list (list-regions region-map))
         (constraints (make-array (list (length node-list) (length node-list)))))
    (loop for (node-a . value) in region-map
      do (loop for node-b in (car value)   
           do (setf (aref constraints  
                          (position node-a node-list)  ;calculating multiple times
                          (position node-b node-list))
                    (not nil))))
    constraints))
```

The usage is as follows and would give an idea of structure of `region-map`:

```
Break 1 [146]> *australia* 
((SA (WA NT Q NSW V)) (WA (NT SA)) (NT (Q SA WA)) (Q (NSW SA NT)) (NSW (V SA Q)) (V (SA NSW)) (T))
Break 1 [146]> (map-coloring-constraint *australia*)
#2A((NIL T T T T T NIL)
    (T NIL T NIL NIL NIL NIL)
    (T T NIL T NIL NIL NIL)
    (T NIL T NIL T NIL NIL)
    (T NIL NIL T NIL T NIL)
    (T NIL NIL NIL T NIL NIL)
    (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL))
```

Is there any better way to write it avoiding the inner loop.

Another question:
I have a variable `a` (which is a list) in the scope and a list `b`. I want to apply a lambda function on each element of b in this scope. This can be achieved with `mapcar`. The problem is I need to access variable `a` inside the lambda function. How can I achieve that.

P.S.: Answer to second question is answer to first as well, hence two question in one post.

Comment: `revaluegion-map`? perhaps there is a copy-paste error?

Comment: @Renzo yeah corrected it. thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second question...  `(let ((a (list 10)) (b (list 1 2 3 4))) (mapcar (lambda (x) (* (car a) x)) b))` already returns `(10 20 30 40)` thus accessing `a` from inside the lambda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling a matrix; two levels of loops is a natural way to do that.
You might be able to avoid the inner loop using [`row-major-aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_row_ma.htm), but I don't see why you would want to.

As for the second question, it is really unclear: if you are trying to access a variable from the outer scope, then it is trivial:

```
(let ((a 2))
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (expt x a))
          '(1 2 3)))
==> (1 4 9)
```

if instead you want to access a variable from the inner scope, then it is impossible:

```
(let ((a 2))
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (expt x a))
          '(1 2 3))
  ;; `x` does not exist anymore, it cannot be accessed
)
```

PS. You might want to modify your code to avoid calling `length` and `position` unnecessarily: these functions are linear in the length of their list argument. Another change you might want to make is replacing `(not nil)` with `t`.